# Does C ever pad a struct before the first element?

Tags: c

Consider an arbitrary struct where the C compiler will perform padding

```
struct node {
  enum type;
  size_t num_children;
  void** nodes;
};
```

Will C ever perform padding before the first element? I ask this as I need to do some funky things with `void*` and require that

```
void* a = node->nodes[0];
enum type t = *(enum type*)(a);
```

will always be evaluated correctly. I'm aware that I can force no padding but would rather not.

Comment: Did you mean to write `*(enum bar *)a`?

Comment: `void* a = node->nodes[0]; ... *a` is invalid code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Will C ever perform padding before the first element?

No. This is explicitly prohibited in the [C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p15):

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in
>   which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in
>   which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably
>   converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
>   **There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>   beginning.**

(emphasis mine).